# Only variables should be passed by reference in... on line 13 Fail

Tags: php, mysql

I'm practicing building a PHP registration form script for a website. I have done this code, but when I click the submit button I get the notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in line 13, and I'm stuck on what to do here. Any help is greatly appreciated, again I'm not a PHP expert.

```
<?php

require 'database.php';

if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):

    //Enter the new user into the database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, username, password) VALUES (:email, :username, :password)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));

    if($stmt->execute() ):
        die('Success');
    else: 
        die('Fail');
    endif;  
endif;

?>
```

here

Comment: Good reference for when you get php errors http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php

Answer (score 4):

change this

```
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
```

to this

```
$email =  $_POST['email'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
$stmt->bindParam(':password',$password);
```

the error message is clear though you need to assign those values into variables then pass them

Answer (score 0):

$result->bindParam(':id', $id, **PDO::PARAM_INT**);

*if string, you need write*:
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username'], **PDO::PARAM_STR**);